# How to send a HTTP 100-continue response with netty

Tags: java, netty, nio, http-status-code-100

I instantiated a netty 4 (using netty-all-4.0.9.jar) service and initialized the channel by adding 3 ChannelHandler objects:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("handler", new MyHandler());
```

When testing w/ curl `HTTP PUT`ing a file to my server and I found `MyHandler.channelRead` is not called immediately for requests with `Expect: 100-continue` header is sent (curl is waiting for the server to reply with `100 Continue`. This means my handler is not able to reply with a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` response to tell the client (curl) to initiate the actual upload of the file immediate.

Interestingly further debugging this issue with `telnet` shows that a `channelRead` is called right once the actual body is being uploaded (right after the first byte is received).

Any hints on how to handle `PUT` requests with 'Expect: 100-continue' header properly to trigger `100 Continue` response immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples coming with netty (e.g. HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java) have the following code in the channelRead() method:

```
if (is100ContinueExpected(req)) {
     ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, CONTINUE));
}
```

Comment: I appears the helloworld handler in the example works fine. I investigated further and found that I had a HttpContentDecompressor in the channel pipeline. Removing it solved my problem. Thanks for the hint with the helloworld handler - working backward from here pointed me the root cause (even though I'm not sure why it behaves like this - you can easily reproduce thgis behavior by adding 'p.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentDecompressor()' to the HttpHelloWorldServerInitializer class.